# Django Rest Framework Hanging on Large ChoiceField

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use the built-in API views from Django Rest Framework for a model that has a foreign key to a massive table.

```
class WidgetAttribute(models.Model):
    widget= models.ForeignKey(Widget, related_name="attributes")
    key = models.TextField()
    value = models.TextField()
```

I have the following serializer.

```
class WidgetAttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = WidgetAttribute
```

Unfortunately, the Widget table contains roughly 5 million rows, and by default DRF is trying to render this as a choice field including all items. That just hangs forever. I've tried using the instructions [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#handling-choicefield-with-large-numbers-of-items) by adding the following line to my serializer:

```
widget = serializers.RelatedField(queryset=Widget.objects.all(), style={'base_template': 'input.html'})
```

But I am still running into the same problem. When I look at program execution, it is still calling the `__unicode__` method on Widget 5 million times. How can I resolve this issue? Ideally I would like going to `/widget/attribute/` to show all existing widgets and then give me a big blank text area to insert data (not broken into choice fields or anything specific). I am not sure if it is relevant, but this is the view I am using:

```
class WidgetAttributeList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = WidgetAttribute
    serializer_class = WidgetAttributeSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('widget', 'key')

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Overwrite the query to check permissions.
        """
        qs_list = [o.id for o in self.model.objects.all() if hasWidgetPerms(self.request.user.client,
                                                                          o.widget)]
        return self.model.objects.filter(id__in=qs_list)
```

Comment: I hope you find an answer. I do direct SQL CLI or `python manage.py shell` when I encounter this problem, which I do not like.  Some sort of autocomplete functionality on the choice field would be awesome.